# Can I set a constant in a class then access it outside in PHP?

Tags: php, constants

I am trying to initialize some values inside a class and save them in constant and access them outside, in different part of my code.

```
<?php

class Config {

  public static function initialize() {
    define('TEST',"This is a Constant");
  }

}

$config = Config::initialize();
// do something with the constants
```

Can I access it outside?

Comment: yes i want to initialize with different settings and access them outside, with this static function

Comment: Your code will define a global constant. Class::constants are a parse-time syntax construct, and cannot be defined later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Class constant uses the `const` keyword. You don't define them using the define function. Just like this:

```
class Config {
        const TEST = "This is a constant";
}

// then use it:
var_dump(Config::TEST);
```

In PHP, you cannot dynamically set the value of a constant, but you can get a similar behaviour with a public static variable. ie.

```
class Config2 {
    public static $test = null;
    public static function initialize()
    {
        self::$test = "This is not a constant";
    }
}

// Then use like
Config2::initialize();
var_dump(Config2::$test);
```

The downside is, there is nothing stopping other code from setting the value from outside the class. If you need protection against this, you should use a getter function approach. eg.

```
class Config3 {
    private static $_test = null;
    public static function initialize()
    {
        self::$_test = "This is not a constant, but can't be changed outside this class";
    }

    public static function getTest()
    {
        return self::$_test;
    }
}

// Then use like
Config3::initialize();
var_dump(Config3::getTest());
```

Comment: the content of the CONSTANT is dynamic, so i can't define it like this

Comment: You cannot dynamically set a constant (AFAIK), I've added some alternate options.

Comment: @Ibu
Brenton Alker is right.
A constant can't be set dynamic.
This is default behaviour in all programming languages.

What you want is a readonly static class variable which is nothing else as a private static variable without a setter, so that it can only be initialize by the constructor.

Comment: Yes @AlexanderBehling, private static was what I was looking for. Although, this question is 10 years old. I learned a thing or 2 along the way.

Comment: The same is true for me.
As PHP has evolved, it would be nonsensical to continue programming the way I learned in 2002. 
Many of the useful commands didn't exist then, so you had to use many tricks to get the code to work anyway. Personally, I like the fact that more OOP features are now available with the PHP 8 release line. Since PHP 5 I have changed my programming style to OOP wherever possible.
I'm curious what will come in the next few years.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Config {
  const TEST = "This is a Constant";

  static public $test = "This is a static property test."
  static protected $test2;

  public static function initialize() {
      self::$test2 = 'initialized';
      return self::$test2;
  }

  public static function getTest2()
  {
      return self::$test2;
  }
}

echo Config::TEST; // outputs This is a Constant
echo Config::$test; // outputs This is a static property test.
echo Config::initialize(); // outputs initialized;
echo Config::getTest2(); // outputs initialized;
```

If you need to dynamically set the value then you dont want to use a constant you want to use a static property. IF you only want the `Config` class to be able to manipulate the value of this property directly then use the `private` or `protected` keyword. If thats a non issue then you could use a `public` property.

Another and perhaps most robust approach depending on what you are trying to implement is to use constants to access static or instance specific properties of the class:

```
class Config
{
  const TEST = 0;
  const TEST2 = 1;

  protected static $conf = array();

  public static function initialize($testVal, $test2Val)
  {
    $conf[self::TEST] = $testVal;
    $conf[self::TEST2] = $test2Val;
  }

  public static function get($key)
  {
     if(isset(self::$conf[$key])
     {
       return self::$conf[$key];
     }
  }
}

Config::initialize('Test', 'Test 2');
echo Config::get(Config::TEST);
echo Config::get(Config::TEST2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not from your original code. But the following would work as a constant class variable.

```
class Config {
    const TEST = "This is a Class Constant";
...
}
```

Accessed from anywhere that includes the `Config` class declaration like:

```
echo Config::TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can access it as `Config::TEST`

Comment: Isn't this the way to access *class* constants? The one in the snippet isn't a class constant.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - defined values can't be set dynamically, so it really doesn't make sense to put them in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all you'll need in this case is a `private` variable with *getter* methods or a class constant.