# Mapping groups of constant values

Tags: php, constants

I have lists where strings correspond with values. For example, in a company list I could have Microsoft correspond with the letters MS.

Obviously, this could be transposed as a table in MySQL to make the list extensible but, from curiosity, how would you express this in constant form in PHP ?

P.S: There is the class-with-constants approach (see accepted answer here: [PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enums)) to act as an enumeration but would that really be of any use seeing that enumerations map to integer values ?

Comment: @Frosty hey you ruined the point in [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137824/152859) lol! :)

Comment: I'm the one-letter-tag killer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using define

```
define("MS","Microsoft");
echo MS;
```

This would echo Microsoft.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Also the link you gave to a possible solution could just as easily be used with strings instead.  The only reason it acts as an enum from other languages is because you define the values from 0 to n, instead of doing that just use string instead.

```
class Companies {
    const MS  = 'Microsoft';
    const IBM = 'International Business Machines';
}

echo Companies::MS;
```

I think this would work.

Comment: Hadn't thought of define. Thanks for the mention. The following is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892226/php-define-constant-inside-a-class

Comment: Saw your edit. The following could be used to reproduce enum-like behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class

Answer (score 1):

i would probably start by looking at [multi dimentional](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php) arrays if a single company can have many corresponding letters, however the draw back being that they can get difficult to manage, your other option is to define [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you have key-value pairs you can put those into an object, so its more practical to use.

check on this link: [the arrayToObject() function](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)