# PHP Defining Global Constants inside a Class

Tags: php, php-5.6, symfony-2.7

In PHP, how do you define a global constant (using the `define` method) inside a class? I would like my constant to be defined *globally* after a class has been instantiated.

Looks like this:

```
class SomethingToInstantiate
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        define('SOMETHING', 'MORE');
    }
}
```

`SomethingToInstantiate` is always instantiated per request, so I could use the `SOMETHING` constant anywhere.

But it seems not to work since PHP can't find the `SOMETHING` constant.

I'm trying to do this with my Symfony 2.7 application.

Inside the `Kernel`'s construct method, since the Kernel is always instantiated per request (and even in the console commands). I'm doing this so that I can access the defined constant anywhere in my code.

But why in Kernel? I've previously defined it in app.php, but it's risky because there three files that I need to edit (which I might forget sometime)

- app.php
- app_dev.php
- console

That's why, instead of editing those three files, I settled to define the constant inside the Kernel's constructor.

Now again, if you're wondering, I'm trying to define the **root dir** as a constant so I can access it anywhere in the application.

Why again? Because I want to be able to parse my custom config files from anywhere in the code, I need the root directory to get the file from /app/config and then parse it.

Then why again? I do not have time to study Custom Config things and somethings, I need to do things quickly!

Why again? I seriously don't want to do this, but there's no other way, the whole codebase sucks! (Yeah, because of the previous development) And I have no time left, lol.

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - define constant inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892226/php-define-constant-inside-a-class)

Comment: :( why use a class with it's lovely scope and namespace ability, and want something back into global pollution? I suggest using a method to obtain the value. `getTheValue() { return $this->theValue;}`

Comment: @ObsidianAge the other question states "*and make it so it's visible only when called in a class context*" this one is about globaL

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/pHiyoe

Comment: ideone.com is PHP 7, but I've also tested it in PHP 5.6.

Comment: Ok, so this one is about Symfony, I'm trying to create the global constant inside the Kernel's construct method, so everytime the Kernel is constructed, I will have the constant in the whole application. Even in the console.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a more complete [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And add the symfony tag.

Comment: "*I'm trying to create the global constant inside the Kernel's construct method*" this sounds so bad. I know sometimes we cannot judge on face value of things. If you explain in more detail then you can get an answer, or perhaps a suggestion for a better way

Comment: yes it sounds so bad, actually the whole codebase is so bad already. I really got no time to fix things up, previous development sucked and lacked resources. I don't have any choice right now lol.

Comment: For whatever reason OP intends to do this, If OP wants to define a globally accessible value inside a local scope, I would recommend creating a Singelton class for all such values, and use that class to set/get values globally

Comment: Ok guys, it seems to work. I think the problem is, the Kernel file is cached or something, so any changes I make in it doesn't reflect until I reset cache. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you @Barmar for testing.