# PHP dinamically define multiple constants inside a class

Tags: php

I have a `class TestClass` and inside it I want to dynamically be able to define a few constants that are stored in $GLOBALS as an array in a `config.php` file:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = [
    'const' => [
        'A' => 'abc',
        'B' => 'def',
        ...
    ]
];
```

Is it possible (and a good practice) to define those constants using a foreach loop at the beginning of the class?

```
class TestClass{
    foreach($GLOBALS['config']['const'] as $k => $v){
       const $k = $v;
    }

    public function doSomething(){
        return self::A;
    }
}
```

Is there's a way to keep all those constants in a simple `config.php` for whatever reason or should I just go and manually set `const` or should I go for `define` inside the `config.php` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - define constant inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892226/php-define-constant-inside-a-class)

Comment: Hey @splash58 that';s not what i want to know, i want to know if it's a good practice to use foreach inside a class to define some constants(and the array is in another file...)

Comment: your foreach now - syntax error

Comment: @splash58 ok, let's say i'm adding it into a function, is it a good practice or should i go the `const` way and forget about the config.php file or should i use `define` in config?

Comment: Just use define in config.php as along as it's always added to every page

Comment: @Second2None, oky, thank you! :D

Comment: No worries, in future if you needed to run code when a class is initialized, you would put it inside function __construct() { //code here } then every time you call $test = new TestClass(); that code would run.

Comment: hmm so basically i could set a few constants inside the constructor if i only need those constants inside that class but i want to have them in a config file so i don't have to go trough that class to change a constant?(i hate seeing ten `define`s one after another :( and i;m trying to avoid that as much as possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly and most important to take a note is avoid `$GLOBALS`. Its very powerful as it is available everywhere but this make it very error prone as it can be modified anywhere in any php script and hence becomes very painful to make sure the keys in `$GLOBALS` are not modified unintentionally. So `$GLOBALS` is a big no specially if you want constants. Now coming to constants , why do you even need to dynamically create constants when you already know the value. So if you know the following

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = [
    'const' => [
        'A' => 'abc',
        'B' => 'def',
        ...
    ]
];
```

It means you know value of A, B, ... etc. So I would suggest you the following:
Create a file  say `constant.php` and define all your constants as below:

```
<?php

define('CONST_A', 'abc');
define('CONST_B', 'def');
```

Now include this file wherever required use `CONST_A` to access the value directly. By this way all you constants are managed at a single place.

Another approach can be by creating a Constant class as below:

```
final class Constant {
    const CONST_A = 'abc';
    const CONST_B = 'def';
    // and more
}
```

Then simply include/use the `Constant` class and access the constants as `Constant::CONST_A`

Comment: Oky, thank you! I'm doing it with `define` even tho i hate seeing 10 define in a row X_X

Comment: :D But all those will be in a single file and you would have to see that file rarely ;)